# Reverter animação no segundo click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Estou a tentar reverter uma simples animação quando carrego novamente num botão. O primeiro click anima um div retirando a sua margem esquerda, mas quando carrego novamente queria voltar a colocar a margem no seu valor normal que são os 250px. Para o efeito decidi usar o toggle do jQuery. A animação da margem corre normalmente mas o problema é que o div também desaparece e reaparece cada vez que pressiono o botão, o que suponho seja o comportamento normal do toggle. O meu código é o seguinte:

```
$("#sidebar-toggle").click(function(){

$("#content").toggle(function(){

    $(this).animate({marginLeft:0},200);
},function(){

    $(this).animate({marginLeft:'250px'},200);
});
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa funcionalidade do `.toogle` em alternar duas funções já foi removida à partir da versão 1.9. O método é usado para esconder/mostrar elementos de forma animada.

Sugiro você não usar `.animate` para isso: use `.toggleClass()` e faça a animação via classe no CSS usando `transition`:

```js
$("#sidebar-toggle").click(function(){
   $("#content").toggleClass("margem");
})
```

```css
#content{
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background: red;
   margin-left: 250px;
   transition: margin-left 200ms;
}

#content.margem{
   margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
<button id="sidebar-toggle">Clique</button>
```

Comment: Perfeito :) muito obrigado!